# Unable to send category in aps object

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, push-notification, objective-c-category

I am trying to send push notification to ios device via firebase and also I need to send category object with the aps payload so that I can create notification with action buttons.  I am using the below payload specified in firebase documentation, but I am unable to receive the category object in the aps payload object in the front end. Any help would be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

```
{
  "message": {
    "token": "f8vYHFfogAA:APA91bG7cZlo7Iimv1UtD0atqTlBRKYsGTU2pdWQmfELpdG61E4_TstS8MNHvHgNJW_dECi8YxD0REiDjxbkBVK4Ey9MNJ4MTxBVJpa48sirKb2a93QyfrpRwDMB9_j8UaNexP5rQ7Ci",
    "notification": {
      "title": "Match update",
      "body": "Arsenal goal in added time, score is now 3-0"
    },
    "android": {
      "ttl": "86400s",
      "notification": {
        "click_action": "OPEN_ACTIVITY_1"
      }
    },
    "apns": {
      "headers": {
        "apns-priority": "100"
      },
      "payload": {
        "aps": {
          "category": "NEW_MESSAGE_CATEGORY"
        }
      }
    },
    "webpush": {
      "headers": {
        "TTL": "86400"
      }
    }
  }
}
```